# install error of massif-visualizer on 14.04

Tags: apt, software-installation, ppa, valgrind

I tried to install `massif-visualizer`. After adding the `kubuntu-ppa/backports` PPA and running `apt-get update`,

```
apt-get install massif-visualizer
```

still gives me an error:

```
E: Unable to locate package massif-visualizer
```

Comment: If you browse the [Kubuntu Backports ppa](https://launchpad.net/~kubuntu-ppa/+archive/ubuntu/backports) it no longer appears to support Trusty - and doesn't seem to include `massif-visualizer` in the series that it does support

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Any other way I can install the massif-visualizer?

Comment: Are you not able to upgrade to 16.04 LTS (or a later supported release) where it appears to be available from the repository? https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/massif-visualizer

Comment: Have to stick to 14.04 ubuntu update

Comment: Could you please open a [new question](/questions/ask) if you have a new or follow-up question? The comment section is not suitable or meant for new questions or extended discussion. You’re welcome to send me a comment with a notification to draw my attention to it. Thanks.